# core-animated-pages/demos/simple.html slide-from-right not working in FF31

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to figure out why the 'slide-from-right'-transition isn't working in FF from my local bower-installed files.
Interesting that calling the same file from the polymer-page http://polymer-project.appspot.com/components/core-animated-pages/demos/simple.html is working.

updating or reinstalling bower-files doesn't help
thx in advance

Comment: works for me in FF in linux

Comment: Done. New Polymer Updates (0.3.5) solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The latest implementation and documentation of animated pages [is here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages).

I got this working in Chrome, by including the specific transition component. And that's what the [demo does](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/simple.html), if you look at its source code.

```
...
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
```

Hth